# Light position in custom shader (Shader Material)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am developing volume rendering app in webgl, and the last thing i have to do is to create a lighting model. I have everything prepared, but i am not able to get the light position in a scene. I am adding the light this way:

```
 var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
 light.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.1).normalize();
 camera.add(light);
```

I attach light to camera, because i need to have light static if i am moving with camera.
Problem is, that i am using ShaderMaterial (custom shader). I am not able to find any uniform variables, that represent light position. I have searched, that i should set:

```
material.lights = true;
```

but it caused errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

I have tried to add constant vector in vertex shader, but i need to multiply by inverse view matrix (if i am right). But GLSL 1.0 doesnt support *inverse* function. I have idea to send inverse view matrix to shader by uniform, but i dont know where can i get view matrix of scene in JS.

Thanks for help. I have tried everything :( ...

Bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to add the light as a child of the camera and set `material.lights = true`, then you must add the camera as a child of the scene.

```
scene.add( camera );
```

three.js r.57

Comment: I have added camera to scene, as you have written. Problem is still here. There is stack of errors:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined Three.js:23486
refreshUniformsLights Three.js:23486
setProgram Three.js:23204
renderBuffer Three.js:21576
renderObjects Three.js:22248
render Three.js:22122
refreshScene

Comment: ok, I have more problems with that... i have to copy uniforms variable from lambert material too :-) error is gone..

Comment: I have changed light to spotlight and print uniforms object.There is variable spotLightPosition ... but if i want to reead from this uniform in shader, than error occured...any idea ?

Comment: uniforms variables are in shader...i dont know why, but the light is still rotatiting with camera..Behaviour of light is not static.. (for controls i am using TrackballControls.js)...

Comment: Ok, last information...
Variable spotLightPosition have still same values..they arent change with camera..light is not depending on camera but on scene...why? :-)

Comment: Man, you sooo forced that accepted answer. It wasn't helpful, since it didn't solved the problem, that were the uniforms...

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to project the light coordinates from model space to screen space using the camera, here's a function (courtesy of Thibaut Despoulain) that might help -

```
var projectOnScreen = function(object, camera)
{
var mat = new THREE.Matrix4();
mat.multiplyMatrices( camera.matrixWorldInverse, object.matrixWorld);
mat.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix , mat);

var c = mat.n44;
var lPos = new THREE.Vector3(mat.n14/c, mat.n24/c, mat.n34/c);
lPos.multiplyScalar(0.5);
lPos.addScalar(0.5);
return lPos;
}
```